# Countif incorrectly matches long number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, countif

In Excel 2013 or 2010, if you put this value in column B1:

```
2014022701000400
```

And then this formula in column C1:

```
=COUNTIF(B1,"2014022701000409")
```

The formula will evaluate to 1. But the numbers are different: the one in the formula ends with a 9, the one in the cell ends with a zero.

Why does `countif` match a value it shouldn't?  Is there a workaround available?

Comment: Not sure why this is, but if you type 2014022701000409 into a cell it converts the 9 to a 0

Comment: A, here you go: http://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel The issue is to do with the way Excel handles over-long numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Like CLockeWork comments it appears to be an issue with long numbers.  The argument to `countif` is treated like a number even if it is too long.

You can force a cell to be text-valued with a `'` character, like `'2014022701000400`.  However that does not work for formula arguments.  The second argument to `countif` does not allow a `'` to force it to be text; it's always interpreted as a number.

One solution is to add an in-between column that prefixes an `a`:

```
2014022701000400
="a" & B1
=COUNTIF(C1,"a2014022701000409")
```

That works, but it ain't pretty.