# Why does Excel round the least significant digit when I paste in a large number?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I paste the number 1542819813881128.5 into a cell of Number format in Excel the pasted value is 1542819813881120.00.

Why do these applications round down the 8.5? Is there a way of preventing this?

Comment: You can only configure Excel to ROUNDUP or ROUNDDOWN, Excel only supports 15 significant digits, so a number in Excel will be rounded in one direction no matter what.

Comment: See also [Adding more than 15 digits in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel). One of the answers suggest to use an addin for large number maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spreadsheets are [not designed for highly accurate calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel). The [IEEE 754 specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) for floating point math calls for only the 15 most significant digits to be stored. If the integer portion of a number is 15 places or longer, [the mantissa or fractional part will be dropped](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel).

The solution is to perform your calculations in something other than a spreadsheet, which is vexing for us who have gotten really good at spreadsheets.

Comment: Mind blown. This is an antiquated constraint.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53292/any-spreadsheet-provide-more-then-double-precision

Comment: @MM01 , no, it is very much current, ubiquitous even in high end computers, and for 99.9999% of all users sufficient. There is very little in this world outside bleeding edge research where so many digits make any sense.